# Android WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not granted

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission designated in the manifest, and in the app when I call requestPermissions, the grantResult comes back with -1, meaning it's not granted. However, in Device Settings for the app, the Storage permission is showing as ON. The app will not let me write, however. Why is the grant request failing, and the permission denied as far as the app is concerned, but showing as fine in Settings?

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
.
.
.
if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
} else {
    //THIS IS WHERE I END UP WITH grantResults == -1
}
```

Comment: Show us your code to find the errors

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: what is for grantresults[1]? you are requesting 2 permissions here

Comment: Either put both permissions in the manifest, or only request the permission that you have in the manifest. Everything listed in `requestPermissions()` needs to appear in the manifest. Also note that you only need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, not both of these permissions.

Comment: It's 0. READ is granted, WRITE is not.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer. Evidently, something I'm pulling in from a 3rd party lib is causing a manifest merger. By adding this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

my problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

May my case help somebody as I noticed a space in my permission in manifest, it was `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE "/>` and I changed it to `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and problem solved. no any other change.